# How do I dynamically add and position CheckBox elements in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I started making a WinForms application to display a grid of 4×4×4 checkboxes, representing a real-life 4<sup>3</sup> grid of LEDs.

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

I want to convert this to an WPF app, so that I can use the transparency option of  the WPF Checkbox, to make the non-selected layer [there will be 4 layers] of checkboxes slightly transparent, to give it a more true 3D feeling.

I am new to WPF and I have tried to nest 2 elements in the main Window [for example, 2 grids to slightly overlap the position, by maybe 20 pixels, so that they would appear to be 3d-staggered], but it simply won't let me do that, and only lets me add a child grid inside the original grid.

**TLDR: How can I dynamically create lots of checkboxes while giving them absolute pixel positions?**

My current working WinForms C# code:

```
int spacing = 25;
int zero = 0;
    for (int z = 1; z <= 4; z++)
            {
                List<string> zString = new List<string>();
                for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
                    {

                        int pixel_x = zero + ((x - 1) * spacing);
                        int pixel_y = (zero - 4) + ((y - 1) * spacing);

                        //int id = ((y - 1) * 4) + x;

                        CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
                        box.CheckStateChanged += new System.EventHandler(checkBox2_CheckedChanged);
                        box.Tag = id;
                        zString.Add(id.ToString());
                        //box.Text = id.ToString();
                        box.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                        //box.
                        box.AutoSize = false;
                        box.Size = new Size(20, 20);
                        box.Padding = new Padding(3);
                        box.Location = new Point(pixel_x, pixel_y);

                        this.Controls.Add(box);
                        id++;
                    }
                }
          zero += 25;
          }
```

Comment: I would start by reviewing [WPF Layouts - A Quick Visual Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) and making sure you're using appropriate panels for this. Ultimately I'd probably have 4 collections of data objects containing a set of checkbox data, and have each collection drawn using an `ItemsControl`. All 4 `ItemsControl` would have a customized `ItemsPanelTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle`, and they'd all be placed in a single panel that allows overlapping children like a `Canvas`

Comment: In WPF, you don't "dynamically create" anything. Instead, you define a proper data model, a proper ViewModel, and then use XAML to define how that data will be rendered on screen. It is a significant mindshift. For the record, all that code you wrote must be deleted. Follow @Rachel's advice of using an `ItemsControl`. That's the way you do any items-based UIs in WPF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this. Use a Canvas inside your Window.

```
<Window x:Name="myWindow1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    >
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" >
    </Canvas>
```

Unlike Location available in Windows Forms, you can use Margin to set the position

```
    int spacing = 100;
int zero = 0;
for (int z = 1; z <= 4; z++)
{
    List<string> zString = new List<string>();
    for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
        {

            int pixel_x =  zero + ((x - 1) * spacing);
            int pixel_y =  zero + ((y - 1) * spacing);

            CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
            Canvas.SetLeft(box, pixel_x);
            Canvas.SetTop(box, pixel_y);

            this.canvas.Children.Add(box);
        }
    }

    zero = zero + 50;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this goes against all known, accepted good practices and patterns in WPF. -1.

Comment: I have tried to keep it closest to his code in Windows Forms. His question is not about binding and best practices in WPF. He has two issues, one regarding a single child in the main window and the other regarding location.

Comment: If you absolutely had to use the same winforms code, I would actually recommend a Canvas and setting Canvas.Top/Canvas.Left rather than using the Margin property

Comment: I tried this and thought it was brilliant, except the problem is, the checkboxes don't all work, since they overlap some of them block others from being clicked.. do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Does it visually overlap?

Comment: @Matt Updated it to use the Canvas to avoid the overlap issue

Comment: @PraveenPaulose, would you know how to reference the Checkboxes by IDs? I have them named "box1" through "box64", and when I try to reference the checkbox it returns null: `CheckBox box = (CheckBox)canvas.FindName(name);` I'm sure that "name" is a valid name, and it always returns null.

Comment: Use this this.canvas.RegisterName(box.Name, box) and then your Find should work. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43ec688f-3af9-400a-92f3-e5933b01b551/discovering-wpf-control-at-run-time-for-a-control-added-at-run-time?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an [ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) ( or DataTemplate) to establish how each item will look within your viewmodel's collection.

Example:

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use multiple `UniformGrid`s stacked on top of each other inside a regular grid (so they overlap). Each UniformGrid would have its Top and Left margins offset by a specific amount.

The item source of each UniformGrid would be bound to a list of Boolean properties on your view model for each "layer".

Comment: I did what you suggest, having a main Grid and programatically adding a UniformGrid for each z-iteration [4 in total]. Look at the result: http://imgur.com/BOc1HwC  My problem is that the CheckBoxes overlap here and there, and block other check-boxes from being checked. I hold ALT and the border thing comes up, see it? Do you have a suggestion? [My code here http://tny.cz/276da4bb ]

Comment: That looks like it's due to the width of each UniformGrid getting smaller as the left margin increases.  You should set the width to some constant value, or set the right margin equal to the inverse of the left margin.  The goal is to keep each inner grid the same width.

Comment: I got this method to work, complete with grid lines using pure MVVM. If you are interested in example code just let me know.

Comment: I posted the solution to bitBucket https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/layer-test/src. It's in VB, but should be easy enough to translate.  It produces the following output. https://imgur.com/tD14XEZ All checkboxes are clickable.